# Cannot connect to Kafka in local Docker container (Windows)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm trying to locally start Kafka in a Docker container, but don't seem to get the combination of options right.

I'm running on Windows 10, Docker ce version 2.0.0.3 (31259).

**What I'm doing**

1. run Zookeeper in Docker container

   `docker run -d --name=zookeeper1 --network=host --env-file=zookeeper_options confluentinc/cp-zookeeper`

I'll leave out the environment file since zookeeper runs fine.

2. run Kafka in Docker container

   `docker run -d --network=host --name=kafka --env-file=kafka_options confluentinc/cp-kafka`

with the `kafka_options` file containing

```
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper1:2181
KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092
```

3. Try to get the metadata list

   `kafkacat -b localhost:29092 -L`

(this I do in Windows 10 Ubuntu subsytem, the others I ran from PowerShell. I also have a small Java Kafka application which exhibits the same behavior though)

The result is

> % ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Broker transport failure

**What I've read**

Obviously the [Quickstart with Docker documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html) which uses docker-compose which I don't want; as well as the [Docker section of the documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/index.html).

Aside from that, most notably [this post by Robin explaining the advertised listeners concept](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/), but I still can't see what I do wrong.

I also found [this issue about a difference in Windows](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/231) preventing you to use the official Quickstart steps in Windows; this lead me try the alternative run with a separate network.

**Separate network**

Following the steps in the issue:

1. `docker network create confluent`
2. `docker run -d --name=zookeeper1 --network=confluent -p 22181:2181 --env-file=zookeeper_options confluentinc/cp-zookeeper`
3. `docker run -d --network=confluent --name=kafka -p 29092:9092 --env-file=kafka_options confluentinc/cp-kafka`
4. `kafkacat -b localhost:29092 -L`

That does change the outcome to

> % ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Timed out

So it looks like at least it connects, but that doesn't help much in the end.

The question is what am I doing wrong? Is it the Kafka configuration options, or is it a Docker issue I'm not aware of?

EDIT:

It does work with the [sample docker-compose.yml here](https://github.com/rmoff/kafka-listeners/blob/master/docker-compose.yml), but shouldn't we be able to start the containers separately?

Comment: How many and which containers are you running in parallel when this happens?